# I can't find the logic error in this easy piece of code. Java language, simple math program

Tags: java

This is a program that is supposed to prompt user for hours worked and hourly
rate of pay, and calculate and display their net pay (including taxes deducted).

I can get this working, but i get the wrong answer and i cant figure out where my logic error is. Please lend a hand and use your expertise. Thanks alot STACK OVERFLOW

```
import java.util.*;
public class HA8PayrollErr {
    public static void main(String[] args){
    float hoursWorked;
    float ratePay;

    float basePay = 0.0f;
    float overtimePay = 0.0f;
    float totalPay = 0.0f;
    float taxDeducted = 0.0f;
    float netPay = 0.0f;

    int doAgain = 0;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    do {
        System.out.println("Enter hours worked this week"); 
        hoursWorked = input.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("Enter rate of pay");
        ratePay = input.nextFloat();

        if (hoursWorked > 37.5f) {
            basePay = 37.5f*ratePay;
            overtimePay = (hoursWorked - 37.5f) * ratePay * 1.5f;
        } else {
            basePay = hoursWorked * ratePay;
        }
        totalPay = basePay + overtimePay;
        if (totalPay < 1000) 
            taxDeducted = 0;
        else if (totalPay > 2000)
            taxDeducted = totalPay *0.30f;
        else taxDeducted = totalPay * 0.20f;

        netPay = totalPay - taxDeducted;

        System.out.println ("Base pay is : $" + basePay);
        System.out.println ("Overtime pay is : $"+ overtimePay);
        System.out.println ("Tax deducted is : $" + taxDeducted);
        System.out.println ("Net pay is : $" + netPay);

        System.out.println ("Enter 0 to repeat, or 1 to quit: ");
        doAgain = input.nextInt();
    } while (doAgain == 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you put a sample execution with the error and the expected result?

Comment: Can you give an example of some erroneous output, and the input you put in? form the looks of it the if statement that works out tax isn't quite right

Comment: What are the logic errors; what is the output you get and what do you expect instead? I do notice a calculation of tax that is not compatible with what I'm used to but I don't know if that is what you're referring to.

Comment: Are these actually programs you've written that you need help with, or is your very assignment to look at the code and figure it out? This is your third "there is a logic error.. what is it?" type question, without any input/output or expected/actual results.

Comment: Please edit your question to provide sample input and expected output; otherwise it makes no sense and I'll have to vote to close it as "not a real question".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not resetting overtimePay on each iteration. So if the person does not have overtimePay on this iteration but did on a previous iteration the value will be added again.

```
if (hoursWorked > 37.5f) {
    basePay = 37.5f*ratePay;
    overtimePay = (hoursWorked - 37.5f) * ratePay * 1.5f;
} else {
    basePay = hoursWorked * ratePay;
    overtimePay = 0.0f;
}
```

Comment: This, and depending on the homework question, tax calculations might need to be progressive instead of fixed rate.

Comment: THANK YOU. YOU SMART COOKIE!!! 

if(YOU > ME) {
System.out.print("THANK YOU David Brainer-Banker");
}